# Retrieve and perform sorting on Array values from the JSON response using BeanShell and JSON extractor or any other way?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jmeter

I was retrieved a JSON response in Jmeter4.0 its look like this:

```
{
   "jsonrpc":"2.0",
   "id":123456789,
   "result":{
      "id":123,
      "name":"Stock",
      "type":"ir.actions.act_window",
      "view_id":false,
      "domain":[
         [
            "id",
            "in",
            [
               4,
               1,
               3
            ]
         ]
      ],
      "xml_id":"stock.action_all",
      "display_name":"Stock"{
         
      }
   }
}
```

I want to perform sorting in that ids (Expected Result: 1,3,4).
How can I achieve this with a BeanShell post-processor or JSON path extractor or any other way on Jmeter 4.0?

Comment: What have you tried yourself with sorting? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) and the following [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) query:

```
sort(result.domain[0][2])
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMESPath `sort()` function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#sort)
- [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.
I have few queries related with your comment
1. Is it supported in jmeter version 4.0 if yes need to add external JAR file or not? 
2. I want to store sorted array result in different variables and pass it to next request can you please suggest how I achieve this?
Can i use result.domain[0][2][1] and use 3 as a value in next request?